# IndexError: pixel index out of range for my pygame paint program (Python 3.2.3)

Tags: python, pygame, paint

I'm making a paint program using pygame, that requires a color palette.

My code is basically:

```
from pygame import *
screen = display.set_mode((1152,864))
color = (0,0,0)

palette = image.load("images/palette.jpg")

paletteRect=Rect(0,675,150,200)
running = True
while running:
    finish = False
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.blit(palette,paletteRect)
    if mb[0] == 1 and paletteRect.collidepoint(mx,my):
        color = spectrum.get_at((mx,my))
```

What happens is it says:     color = palette.get_at((mx,my)) IndexError: pixel index out of range

However, if I change it to paletteRect = palette.get_rect(), my color palette works perfectly fine. Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload "palette.jpg" somewhere so we can test your program?

Comment: Please also fix the code sample you have posted - it does not run due to numerous errors

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your problem is that `(mx, my)` represents a screen coordinate (although it's hard to say since you've not included this part of your code), so when a click collides with your `paletteRect`, it's coordinates will be something like `(10, 700)` which is outside of your `palette` image size.

You need to subtract the position of your palette on screen from the mouse x & y coords:

```
color = palette.get_at((mx-paletteRect.x, my-paletteRect.y))
```